# How to perform Select,Insert,Delete operation on Cosmos DB

Tags: mongodb, azure, azure-cosmosdb

I wanted to perform CRUD operations on azure-cosmosdb using the query on azure query-explorer.
How can I construct insert, update and delete query here.

I am unable to construct a single query.

I am constructing the query here:

[image: query window]

Comment: There is an entire documentation page on SQL for DocumentDB API. Have you read through that yet? That's where to start. Also, there are no SQL-based update/delete operations supported; those are specifically done through API/SDK calls. And... not sure what you mean by not being able to construct a single query. What have you tried? Where are you stuck? As written, this question is off-topic, as it's essentially a tutorial recommendation question.

Comment: What mean to say is to execute an query on query explorer. Please see the image i have attached

Comment: Ok yes I see your query, but I don't understand what problem you're having.  Your `select` statement seems valid. Is it showing an error? Please edit your question with more details, since it looks fine.

Comment: Sir, The query which is shown is default query. I just need some help on insert delete and update query

Comment: Ok, as I explained: look at the Cosmos DB page - there is an entire documentation page set up explaining the entire SQL query feature set. This is not the place to just document random example queries (with no context, no knowledge of your data schema...). And also, as I explained, there are no delete and update operations through SQL - that is all API-driven.

Comment: I am confused as many documents their. I am totally new to Mongo Db and Document DB. It will be helpful if you can just put a link here

Comment: Just... google... `DocumentDB SQL`. It's *that* easy.

Comment: as per the document when I do `db.families.find({ id: “WakefieldFamily”})` on the same shell which i shown in my picture its giving me error saying `Syntax error, incorrect syntax near 'db'.`

Comment: You can't keep putting details in comments - this is not a discussion board. Also: You're now asking about issues executing queries with MongoDB syntax (which requires you to create a MongoDB API collection), not DocumentDB SQL. All of this is explained in the docs. Please start there, then ask specific questions here.

Comment: As  David Makogon  mentioned that  `Select,Insert,Delete operation on Cosmos DB` is not suppported from the azure portal query-explorer currently. And there is a  smilar [feedback](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/263030-documentdb/suggestions/6346033-set-based-operations-insert-update-delete) it is under review by Azure team. If wan to do perform Select,Insert,Delete operation on Cosmos DB we could use  [DocumentDB/Cosmos DB
 API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/documentdb/) or SDK to do that.

Answer (score 2):

The Query Explorer you are showing responds to Cosmos DB [SQL syntax queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-sql-query), not Mongo Query syntax (you can't do `db.yourCollection.find` for example).

When you create your Cosmos DB account, you can select if you want to use the [Mongo API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/documentdb/documentdb-protocol-mongodb). If you are indeed working on a project that will use Mongo and you enable the Mongo API, you can run queries using Mongo syntax in the **Data Explorer** (in Preview) which is in the same vertical navigation menu.

The Data Explorer, for a Mongo-enabled Cosmos DB account, includes a **Mongo Shell** that let's you run the kind of commands you are looking for.

[image: Mongo shell access]